# Dialogflow Fulfillment for Java client library

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am migrating our dialog flow agent to use V2 API. Our V1 implementation uses Java client library from dialog-flow(api-ai). Our web service receives the request on webhook endpoint which is configured to invoke 'doWebook' method.

**Below is the V1 implementation where I use AIWebhookRequest and Fulfillment**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Fulfillment output = new Fulfillment();
    doWebhook(gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), AIWebhookRequest.class), output);

    response.setCharacterEncoding(RESPONSE_CHARACTER_ENCODING);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    gson.toJson(output, response.getWriter());
}

/** handle the actions passed by Google Home intents **/
protected void doWebhook(AIWebhookRequest input, Fulfillment output) {.....}
```

**I am trying to utilize google-cloud-dialogflow-v2 java library now with the following changes**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Fulfillment output = new Fulfillment(); // ** This is still V1, What could I use from V2 here??**
    doWebhook(gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), *WebhookRequest*.class), output);

    response.setCharacterEncoding(RESPONSE_CHARACTER_ENCODING);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    gson.toJson(output, response.getWriter());
}

/** handle the actions passed by Google Home intents **/
protected void doWebhook(*WebhookRequest* input, *WebhookResponse* output) {.....}
```

My question is on the line

**Fulfillment output = new Fulfillment(); // This is still V1, What could I use from V2 here??**

Comment: You can't use a WebhookResponse type for output?

Comment: WebhookResponse is a final class with a private constructor hence unlike Fulfillment it is not instantiable.

Comment: There's no WebhookResponse.Builder class?

Comment: You've tagged this `google-assistant-sdk`, but you haven't said anything about Actions on Google. Are you using this with the Google Assistant? Or is this for a variety of Dialogflow integrations?